# Entity "Defragmentation" constraint solver/algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree, fragmentation

**Update**:

A entity is an object created with attributes/methods of a given entity template. A entity may have a parent and/or a number of children.

Every entity template has a thread fragmentation cost and a computer fragmentation cost. They define how costly it will be to have children of that entity on different computers/thread from the parent

New entities will be assigned to a computer and a thread at the end of every iteration (via add) and old entities may be reassigned to a computer and a thread at the end of every N iteration (via defragment).

When add is invoked, a entity is created and attached to a given parent. However, it still still has to be placed in a computer's thread's simulation runner.

The factors deciding assignment are the child {computer|thread} fragmentation costs and optionally the fragmentation cost matrix.

---

### **Original**

Hi,

I'm just looking to get some ideas on a general direction/algorithm/field to solve the following problem.

I have N Entities (each with a possible parent and possible M children) in an **iterative realtime simulation** environment. Each entity is placed in a server environment where it is located on **1 computer and 1 thread on that computer**. Each entity has a **"computer fragmentation cost" and "thread fragmentation cost"**, which is a value from 0->1 (with 1 being the most expensive) that defines **how painful/costly** it will be to have that **entity's children on different computers or threads**. "computer fragmentation cost" will be higher than "thread fragmentation cost".

I have 2 operation. A "add" operation that's executed when a entity is initially added. I also have a "defragment" operation that runs at the end of every Y iterations that relocates entities to different threads/computers.

What is a general algorithm/guideline that makes sure the fragmentation stays at a minimum for those 2 operations, given the fragmentation costs?

Also, each entity is created from a predefined template. There will be a matrix defining the fragmentation costs between every pair of entity template. How can this additional data be used to lower fragmentation?

Thanks

Comment: Do you know *in advance* when each entity will be created, and how long it will run for?

Comment: You do not have enough information here for us to help you.  In particular we need to know how and when Entities are assigned to Computers/Threads, when the "algorithim" would be applied or come into play, and what other events/factors/considerations will either invoke or affect assignment and more importantly when.

Comment: @j_random_hacker. No. The whole system is dynamic

@RBarryYoung. Updated.

Comment: No one has any suggestions? :(

Comment: jameszhao00: it's a complex subject area and the abstractness of it is a little confusing and off-putting.

Comment: I think that there's still something missing here:  As currently stated, the answer is to schedule everything on one thread on one computer.  So there must be a contravening cost factor that you want balanced against the fragmentation costs.

Comment: (I'm guessing that the balancing cost factor is going to be something like total run-time or effective utilization of all computers and worker threads)

Comment: Yea barry forgot to mention that. The other factor at work here will be some form of force that tries to move entities form crowded nodes to less crowded nodes.

Comment: Hmm maybe I should clean this question up and repost it.

Comment: Just saw this. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment%5Fproblem

Think its the same problem with a customized cost equation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283644/assignment-algorithm

Comment: Yes, the Assignment/General Assignment problem is one possible solution for your problem.  But I cannot say, because their applicability depends very strongly on 1) what you are really trying to globally optimize (your fragmentation costs alone are insufficient) and 2) whether those cost's are stable and static or change dynamically according to the current simulation state.  The Assignment problem(s) usual solutions assume an overall cost matrix and either stable costs or cost related to linear equations of the state.

Comment: On the other hand, most of my simulations work has been in Systems Performance Queuing Networks (QN), whose costs change according to non-closed and highly non-linear equations of the state and cannot be practically solved with the same techniques.